# Forcing a \list item to align with the top of it's contents in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm working on typing up some homework in LaTeX. Some of the questions have multiple parts. For one of them I have to inserted a table. The problem is the item label gets centered vertically with respect to the table, however, I'd prefer the label to be aligned at the top. To see what I'm talking about you can view the output here: http://ianburris.com/dropbox/public/so/q2/hw1.pdf and look at problem 5 part b. Also, here is the code for that portion:

```
\item
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    pushi & 0\\ 
    load & 15\\ 
    pushi & 12\\ 
    alu.sub & \\ 
    pushi & 0\\ 
    store & 5\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

How would do I force the label to align with the top of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an optional parameter to `tabular` for vertical alignment of the tabular within the line. Try this:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
```

Comment: This seems to align to the 'baseline' of the item text, i.e. the top of the tabular is at the same y-coord as the bottom of the letters in the item text. Is there a way to align it to the top of the letters, such that the first row of the table flows in the same row of text as the item text?